# How do I send a http post request to a website's api in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, twitter, request, http-post

How do I send a http post request to a website? for example:

```
HTTP POST Request to http://api.twitter.com/user_friendslist/json
```

(I made up that url)
I'm not sure how to request with ruby using a url. 
Please help :\ 
& Thank you for your time and consideration

EDIT: Do I use Curb gem?

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
 <%= button_to("Twitter","http://api.twitter.com/user_friendslist/json", method: :post) %>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with just ruby for now, not ruby on rails :\